# Rotation of Turtlebot in Gazebo Environment

Tags: turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I was moving turtlebot robot in gazebo environment, I sent the publication to the topic`/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi` to rotate the turtlebot. My publication was like this:

`rostopic pub /cmd_vel_mux/input/navi geometry_msgs/Twist -- '[0, 0, 0]' '[0, 0, 3.14]'`

However, the robot did not rotate in 180 degree. I was expecting that it rotates around itself 180 degree.
Is there anyone who knows its reason ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334663/rotation-of-turtlebot-in-gazebo-environment/) by [gktg1514](https://answers.ros.org/users/37700/gktg1514/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2019-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`geometry_msgs/Twist` encodes *velocity*, not position.

From [the documentation](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html):

> ```
> This expresses velocity in free space broken into its linear and angular parts.
> ```

Your `rostopic pub` command line would be publishing a rotation at 3.14 rad/s around the Z axis.

So the total rotation depends on the duration for which you publish that message.

If you want to rotate the robot (*any* robot that exposes the same `Twist` interface) a certain angle, you'll have to publish the `Twist` for as long as needed. [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) would be a good source of info on what the current pose of your robot is and could be used to close a position loop over this velocity control interface.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1